Debezium SQL Server is throwing OutOfMemory Error after a restart
We are using debezium SQL Server Connector v2.6.1.Final & Kafka Connect v3.7.0 to send data from SQL Server database to Kinesis 1.14.8 and from there to our downstream
So the initial snapshot we were able to complete it perfectly with using just 2GB of memory for 200 Million data, and then update of 10M records we were able to do it and then if I restart my debezium server. I see thousands of below logs with some slight variation but it says Skipping change as its currentChangePosition is smaller than the last recorded position and eventually hitting my container heap memory limit which is 10GB and bringing down my container
Skipping change ChangeTableResultSet{changeTable=Capture instance "dbo_RatingLevelData_tbl" [sourceTableId=RatingsData.dbo.RatingLevelData_tbl, changeTableId=RatingsData.cdc.dbo_RatingLevelData_tbl_CT, startLsn=0000bcb9:00030d89:0001, changeTableObjectId=361820401, stopLsn=NULL], resultSet=SQLServerResultSet:10, completed=false, currentChangePosition=0000bf96:0001fad6:004e(0000bf53:0001059a:0003)} as its position is smaller than the last recorded position 0000bf96:0001fad6:004e(0000bf96:0001fad6:004d)

As far as I know when there is a restart of debezium server, it tries to read from where it left off, and for SQL Server it actually reads from Change tables, if there are records in change table debezium tries to get them in memory and read them and skip them if it is already processed. So in this process it is loading 10M records in its memory which is causing to spend all the heap memory.
text
How can we prevent this from happening. We'd greatly appreciate any insights or assistance you could provide in pinpointing and resolving this issue

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
